# Using Tab Controls in a combobox

Tags: c#

I want to find alternate of tab control in  c sharp project.
Esentialy Tab control is great to use, but as my need over 20 controls, TabControls will be a mess. Instead of showing tabs in a line, I want to use a combobox,which will act as tab control.

I search stackoverflow as well as other sources but nothing found helpful. I need to implement it in Windows Form. Any Idea Geeks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create your own control inherited from TabControl and hide its tab headers area. Then react on your combo box selection change by selecting proper tab. In order to hide tab area you should add this code to the descendant of TabControl

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x1328 && !DesignMode)
        m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
    else
        base.WndProc(ref m);

}
```

Comment: Thanks Demarsch. I'd try that sure.

Comment: Great tips indeed, after a long long time I came here again'